# Assumption of proof with contrapositive

Tags: real-analysis, logic

I want to prove by proof with contrapositive that

$\left \| u(0) \right \|=0 $ then $\left \| u(t) \right \|=0$ for all t belongs to $\left [ 0,T \right ]$.

Then I write

$\left \| u(t) \right \|\neq 0$ then $\left \| u(0) \right \|\neq 0$ for all t belongs to $\left [ 0,T \right ]$.

Is it correct ?

Comment: $u:t \mapsto t^2$?

Comment: The contraposition argument you made is correct. Now you have to prove it.

Comment: The contraposition argument is not correct. The right one is if IT EXISTS $t_0 \in [0,T]$ such that  $\Vert u(t_0) \Vert \neq 0$ then $\Vert u(0) \Vert \neq 0$.

Comment: This is an example were it is important to write with proper quantification and not be too attached with "English" instead of symbols. What's the starting the statement supposed to be: $(1)$ or $(2)$?
$$
\left\Vert u(0)\right\Vert=0\implies \forall t\in [0,T]\left(\left\Vert u(t)\right\Vert=0\right)\tag 1
$$
$$
\forall t\in [0,T]\left(\left\Vert u(0)\right\Vert=0\implies \left\Vert u(t)\right\Vert=0\right)\tag 2
$$

Comment: The statement (2).

Answer (score 1):

The contrapositive of

If $∥u(0))∥=0$, then $‖u(t))‖=0$ for all $t$ belonging to $[0,T]$.

is the following:

If $‖u(t))‖\ne 0$ for some $t$ belonging to $[0,T]$, then $∥u(0))∥\ne 0$.

Comment: I can find                                            
                                                                    
$\left \| u(t) \right \|\neq 0$     for all t belongs to $\left [ 0,T \right]$  then

  $\left \| u(t) \right \|$ $<=$ 
$\left \| u(0) \right \|$ .
This is the proof of what ?

Comment: You have proved your point by contrapositive,  because in that case$ \left \| u(0) \right \|\neq 0$ is evident from $ \left \| u(t) \right \|\le \left \| u(0) \right \|$

Comment: Under the assumption that        
    $\left \| u(t) \right \|\neq 0$     for all t belongs to $\left [ 0,T \right]$ 
I find that
 $\left \| u(t) \right \|$ $<=$
$\left \| u(0) \right \|$ .
Is this implies that        
 
$\left \| u(0)\right \|=0 $ then $\left \| u(t) \right \|=0$ for all t belongs to $\left [ 0,T \right ]$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

The contrapositive of "A implies B" is "not B implies not A". In this case A is $\Vert u(0) \Vert = 0$ and B is $\Vert u(t)   \Vert = 0$ for all $t \in [0, T].$ Not A is clearly $\Vert u(0) \Vert \not= 0.$ What about not B? If it is not true that something happens for every $t \in [0, T],$ it means that there is at least one value of $t$ in the interval for which that something doesn't happen. In other words, there exists $t_0 \in [0, T]$ such that $\Vert u(t_0) \Vert \not= 0.$

So what you have to prove is that if there exists $t_0 \in [0, T]$ such that $\Vert u(t_0) \Vert \not= 0,$ then $\Vert u(0) \Vert \not= 0.$

Comment: What about the assumption if I add that the function $u$  is   a continuous function on $\left [ 0,T \right]$    ?